# how to update value of the specific column from a table after deleting data

Tags: php

guy's i need help for this problem guy's
i have a table with 4 column. `no, name, address, phone`. the case is after i do deleting one data i must decrease column `no` with how many data i delete.

last time i make a program using vb.net i can do this. i use this code i can do it well

```html
Dim ab As Integer
                ab = lvrak.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text
                Dim stok As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Update tbl_barangluar set jumlah_barang=jumlah_barang - '" & ab & "' where kode_barang='" & _
        lvrak.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text & "'")
                stok.Connection = koneksi
                stok.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but now i need to do that in php function. and im really dont know how to do it.
i try just do `ex. update temp5 set no='$no' - 1` and it not going well. someone please help me

**This my Trial PHP**

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");


 $no= $_POST['no_check'];
   
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "DELETE FROM temp5 WHERE no='$no'";

if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    echo "Records were deleted successfully.";
 
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($db);
?>
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");


 $no= $_POST['no_check'];
   
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "alter table temp5 auto_increment = 1";

if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    echo "Records were deleted successfully.";
 
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($db);
?>
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

 $no= $_POST['no_check'];
 $min = 1;
 
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "UPDATE temp5 SET  no=no -1 where no";
if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully."; 

} else{
    echo "Records inserted failed ";
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

I will add a picture before and after delete function has do.
the problem is there. i have try to do limiting them but is give more eror.
in the 1st picture is contain all the data before delete. and i will do delete the data with `no 4`. and the result is in picture 2. that result is wrong.. the result must be `1,2,3,4`

[image]

[image]

Comment: show your php code

Comment: my php code not running well w8 i will edit in my question

Comment: where is  your deleting rows part . i don't see that part in you post

Comment: ok w8.. i will edit it again

Comment: i want the update procedure will update all rows in the column `no`. because of that i use that `update temp5 set no = no -1 where no`

Comment: it should be inside the delete success if  UPDATE temp5 SET  no=no -1

Comment: without where no?

Comment: nice dude.. it works..
hahahha... the function almost same with in vb.net T_T. i must try to know more about php

Comment: what you mean with inside the delete succes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the count after delete `success`

```
UPDATE temp5 SET no=no -1
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");
       $no= $_POST['no_check']; 
       $sql = "DELETE FROM temp5 WHERE no='$no'"; 
      if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){ 

         $sql1 = "UPDATE temp5 SET no=no -1"; 
         mysqli_query($db, $sql1);

      } else{

        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db); 

       }
```

Comment: like this? dude

Comment: `<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");


 $no= $_POST['no_check'];
   
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "DELETE FROM temp5 WHERE no='$no'";

if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    $sql = "UPDATE temp5 SET  no=no +1";
 
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
}`

Comment: ehhehe... bad connection dude

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\192.168.1.22\php\absen\spl_delete_data.php`

Comment: unexpected } before else

Comment: missed semicolon at the end of this line  mysqli_query($db, $sql1);

Comment: i think its running.
thx dude.
btw. can i ask a favor again? did you have any reference about trigger in mysql ( i need for study more php and mysqli)

Comment: @ JYoThl when i want add one more condition where i must place the condition dude?
inside the success function or outside of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149918/discussion-between-minervaz-mine-and-jyothi).

Comment: @JYoThl dude.. im still has problem here

Comment: what is the issue ? @MinervazMine

Comment: @JYoThl the issue is when the update function run.
it just update below the maks number,

example.. i have `no with data 1,2,3,4,5` then do delete and do update the `no` with condition do delete `no 4`. the result will be like this `no with data 0,1,2,3,5`

Comment: i try to embed limit.. but the update cant be running. and it make my code count as eror

Comment: @JYoThl i try edit you answer with add the problem that i got. you can see the picture that i add there

Comment: @JYothl sorry.. my mistake

Comment: @JYoThl you can see my edit there. i have edit them. i just add the screen shot before and after deleting. the problem is in that picture. it was wrong result come. the right result must be `1,2,3,4`. i have try to give `LIMIT 0` in the update inside delete but make the function cant be run

Comment: @JYoThl you can see my edit there. i have edit them. i just add the screen shot before and after deleting. the problem is in that picture. it was wrong result come. the right result must be `1,2,3,4`. i have try to give `LIMIT 0` in the update inside delete but make the function cant be run